# How to display limited brands in bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I am setting up a store in bigcommerce. In my theme there is a list of brands on the bottom of the page. It is displaying 10 brand names and i want to display only 4 or 5 brand names. can anyone help me how i can limit brands?

Answer (score 0):

Hardeep, you'll need to use a javascript that removes the extra list items. Possibly just use jQuery slice

```
$(".Brands ul li").slice(5).remove();
```

http://api.jquery.com/slice/